How to restrict OpenAI answers only from embeddings?
currently i’m saving chunk of data inside of a vector database more specifically pine-cone, when im trying to ask OpenAI questions of this chunk of data it answers correctly but sometimes not , my questions is how to increase the accuracy of the replies and also restrict OpenAi to only answer from that database.
I tried adding orders in the prompt like " Your task is to extract detailed answers from the database promptly, including all minor information and personnel details without seeking additional context "
